# Why doesn't uWSGI compile my django localization files?

Tags: django, apache, internationalization, uwsgi

When I restarted my apache server (+mod_wsgi) with my django project, it recompiled django.po files into new django mo files which are used in internationalization.

Now I try uWSGI server, and it doesn't do this. Why this happens? or is it normal for uWSGI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not something django is supposed to do (independently by the application server). Maybe you have some mod_wsgi config (or a modified .wsgi file) for calling:

django-admin.py compilemessages

or something similar.

Be sure to use the same .wsgi file in uWSGI (with --wsgi-file option), or double check mod_wsgi options.

Comment: The easy way for me was just adding "compilemessages" to my deploy-script. But I'll mark it as correct for now=)